# Does anyone understand what the problem with Pandas could be here? I am just trying to read an excel file

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

```
import pandas

path = r"C:\Users\david\Documents\Excel\BitcoinPricesCopy.xlsx"

file = pandas.read_excel(path)

print(file)
```

***Error:***

> File
> "C:\Users\david\Programming\MyPython\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\numbers.py",
> line 4, in 
> file = pandas.read_excel(path) AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_excel' (most likely
> due to a circular import)

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from your fiename `numbers.py` as `numbers` is an existing python module and probably imported in the `pandas` one somewhere.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html

This causes circular import as stated in the error, so you should rename your file.

Check this about circular imports: [What happens when using mutual or circular (cyclic) imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/what-happens-when-using-mutual-or-circular-cyclic-imports-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error, it seems that the name of your python file is `numbers.py`: this is the issue. Probably, it clashes with a module that Pandas loads (e.g., [numbers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html); so, change the name of your script and the issue should be solved.

Moreover, mind that to read `xlsx` files you need to use the right engine: you can choose the right one with the parameter `engine` of the [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) function (e.g., `openpyxl`).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your filename is Pandas.py that's why read_excel is unable to import its dependencies to read the xlsx file. Try renaming the file and then run

Comment: The file is called numbers.py, so i guess that cannot be the problem...